# Lambda is not triggering SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using lambda integration.

My flow is:

`SQS -> labmda -> SNS (on async fail/suc).`

Problem is, that after lambda function SNS is not triggered. What is wrong? SQS is definitely async execution.

How to debug?

Any hints?

There is my Access policy for SNS:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:044739556748:LambdaNotification",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "044739556748"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share code snipper and how you setup the resources, any cloudformation ?

Comment: Have you gave the lambda the correct permissions to publish to sns?

Comment: Wich code snipper , I just click services in AWS GUI, there is no code http://prntscr.com/uj2j44

Comment: For lambda (just for testing) I put FULLACCES to SQS and SNS

Comment: I added sns access policy

Comment: Should I allow lambda in sns policy? How?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have configured a Lambda function triggered from SQS.

First debug:
These issue happens when we mix the async and sync method. Can you please verify the lifecycle of SQS from sending the message to Queue, Message in flight and deletion of message.

Second debug:
Please check if your Lambda execution role has required permissions to execute your request in regards to SQS & SNS

Third debug:
Please check if your Lambda code has any error

Fourth debug:
Please do not use async function in Lambda. Instead you make the record loop async.

E.g.

```
export.handler = function(event, context)
if(event.Records){
   event.Records.forEach(async(record))=>{
     await ProcessQueue(record)
   }
}

const ProcessQueue=(record)=>{
  // Put your logic here
}
```

Comment: Sending from SQS can be sync? I think is async everytime, or not?

Comment: Yes, can be both. For sync it has to be confirmed by consumer or message should be deleted. Otherwise it will keep moving from queue to flight and again back

Comment: I can't see any settings in my SQS how to set async, I am sending demo messages from AWS GUI http://prntscr.com/uj2x7u

Comment: If you are not using FIFO then it's async. If you go to your Queue list, you can actually see the number of messages in queue and in flight. Keep refreshing the page and you will see the count. Till the time the message is not consumed by any receiver and confirmed it will remain in queue as per retention time configured.

Comment: Is possible trigger async job via api gateway?

Comment: Yes, actually I did recently. Here's the flow. I created two Lambda functions: One for Sending the message via API Gateway another function to Process that message. I have got Processing Lambda function triggered from SQS Queue. Let me know if I can share in details.